# How do I get Python and ColdFusion to work together using CORBA on Windows?

Tags: python, coldfusion, corba

This just seems like something that is easy but I can't find any data on it.

Comment: why CORBA? any chance you can use RESTful-style web services instead?

Comment: CORBA was a client requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read http://www.forta.com/books/0321292693/0321292693_chapter28.pdf